How to stop getting whatsapp messages from websites I visit?
Whenever I visit some website I receive whatsapp messages from them.
For eg. I visited this Bombay shaving website and after that I received below message. I did not do anything on website like providing any access or anything, I just scrolled a little bit and closed the page.
Is there any setting by which I can stop this?


Could you add the link to some websites that do this?

@AndrewT. this is the one I shared above. Bombay shaving company.  I got coupon in one of of the payment app. I clicked redeem which opened their website in integrated browser and thats it, I did not like the product they shown so I closed it. And then got this message from them on whatsapp.

This does not happen normally. The browser had no knowledge of your mobile number. Options..

You may have visited a related website where you did provide the information and its being shared.  Use the privacy options to clear your  history.
Or you have a virus or malware. Run a decent scanner. Many, such as Kaspersky have free versions.


I got coupon in one of of the payment app. I clicked redeem which opened their website in integrated browser and thats it, I did not like the product they shown so I closed it. And then got this message from them on whatsapp.

The undisclosed payment app leaked your info when you used (or tried to use the coupon). Somewhere there must have been a T&C link saying that would happen.
